# Measure performance of React Native apps

Tags: performance, react-native

I need to measure the performance of a React Native app. What's the best tool for this?

I try  google trace in google chrome, and Instruments in mac for iOS platform, but these show me a lot of unorganized data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I implemented some tools that helped me to check my application's performance, below is the list of the tools:

1) (reactotron) https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

It's the coolest way to get logs of your application(redux actions etc), I have integrated this tool in my projects, in case you need any help just feel free to ask.

2) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html (`react-addons-perf`)

This tool tells you about the frames/s,instances etc.. This is a react tool, it possible to integrate with react native.

> Use the built-in Profiler to get detailed information about work done
>   in the JavaScript thread and main thread side-by-side.
>
> For iOS, Instruments are an invaluable tool, and on Android you should
>   learn to use systrace.
>
> You can also use react-addons-perf to get insights into where React is
>   spending time when rendering your components.
>
> Another way to profile JavaScript is to use the Chrome profiler while
>   debugging. This won't give you accurate results as the code is running
>   in Chrome but will give you a general idea of where bottlenecks might
>   be.

Note: The above tools are for monitoring javascript performance, for example time took to rendering of components, which action in redux is getting inbetween the flow of regular actions..

Cheers :)

Comment: As of React 16, react-addons-perf is not supported. https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html