# How to measure performance of react-native app

Tags: performance, react-native, performance-testing

I am using react-native 0.52.0 and react- 16.2.0 . My react-native application runs slowly. I want to optimize its performance. Can anyone tell me what are the ways in which we can make react native app faster and how to measure its performance and memory usage? Is there any tool to measure its overall performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measure performance of React Native apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701755/measure-performance-of-react-native-apps)

Comment: @RafaelTavares The link you provided helps me with performance improvement but i am looking for every possible memory leakages and ways to minimize it. and many other things related with it. in that way the provided answer is not sufficient for me..but thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 6):

1) (reactotron) https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

It streams to you information about your app’s state, API calls, benchmarks, exceptions, and other stuff.

2) https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html

This page contains all you need to check for performance in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Studio Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile) to monitor memory usage on Android. Take into account that you will need Android 10 for the  profileable tag in Android Manifest to work.